# apple music automatically plays song 20 times

Tags: itunes, music

When hitting `play` in iTunes on a song or album this song is automatically added to the `play next` list 20 times.

I added a GIF to illustrate whats happening: 
[image]

So far I've only restarted my Mac multiple times and quit and reopened the music app to no avail.

**Is there any way to reset this?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have "repeat title" or "repeat all" switched on?

I assume those are all the same titles, not like an album with 20 remixes.

Comment: OMG I really thought I had turned both off, but I just checked again. Thanks :) I find it weird though that the song is added 20 times to play next.